# Two component.ts files point towards same component.html file

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to split my functions inside my first.component.ts file to another second.component.ts file make it more readable.

I am pointing to the same component.html file from both ts files like this:

first.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'first-component',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss'],
})
```

second.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'second-component',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss'],
})
```

By doing this, I get errors that functions that are in the second component are missing in the first component and that other way around. This is because when I use the functions in the HTML they check for them in both of the .ts files.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Use a service or split your template into multiple components with respective templates. Your approach isn't advisable IMHO.

Comment: Maybe a shared component for both first & second components.

Comment: why do you want to have two components with same HTML but different functions?
Maybe it's better to have a common Parent component and then two child components

Comment: I believe the best thing would be a composition - i e several container components with just a shared component rendered in them.  or you could try to make simillar thing with the help of inheritance, both ways bring their own limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two separate components.

Just because you declare the same template does NOT mean it merges them into a single one.

If you want to split your code for more readability, then use the Anguar features to do so : services, directives, pipelines, Input/Output ...

Comment: Thanks, trying to split the code in a service now and injecting the service in the constructor.